# How to capitalize all letters in a paragraph

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm trying to write a macro to reassign paragraph styles from the Word defaults to styles defined by a third-party application. I have to apply the new style or the import doesn't work correctly.

Some styles (SCT, PRT, ART) should also be in ALL CAPITAL LETTERS but many times the document author doesn't follow that format. I need a way to apply capitalize the text of the entire paragraph while I change the style.

I tried ojbPara.Range.text = UCase(ojbPara.Range.text). I also tried assigning the text the AllCaps = True property.

All the style matching code and font changes at the bottom work without the capitalizing part. I'd also be up any suggestions if there's a better way to write the rest of the macro.

```
Sub ChangeStyle()

Dim objPara As Paragraph
Dim previousOriginalStyle As Style

'junk style to use for first item
Set previousOriginalStyle = ActiveDocument.Styles("Quote")

'swap styles, if preceding style is different, use "lc" style

For Each objPara In ActiveDocument.Paragraphs

    If objPara.Style = "Header" Then
        objPara.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("SCT")

        ElseIf objPara.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("Heading 1") Then
            objPara.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("PRT")
            previousOriginalStyle = ActiveDocument.Styles("Heading 1")

        ElseIf objPara.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("Heading 2") Then
            objPara.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("ART")
            previousOriginalStyle = ActiveDocument.Styles("Heading 2")

        ElseIf objPara.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("Heading 3") Then

            If objPara.Style = previousOriginalStyle Then
                objPara.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("PR1")
            Else: objPara.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("PR1lc")
            End If
            previousOriginalStyle = ActiveDocument.Styles("Heading 3")

        ElseIf objPara.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("Heading 4") Then

            If objPara.Style = previousOriginalStyle Then
                objPara.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("PR2")
            Else: objPara.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("PR2lc")
            End If
            previousOriginalStyle = ActiveDocument.Styles("Heading 4")

        ElseIf objPara.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("Heading 5") Then

            If objPara.Style = previousOriginalStyle Then
                objPara.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("PR3")
            Else: objPara.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("PR3lc")
            End If
            previousOriginalStyle = ActiveDocument.Styles("Heading 5")

        ElseIf objPara.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("Heading 6") Then

            If objPara.Style = previousOriginalStyle Then
                objPara.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("PR4")
            Else: objPara.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("PR4lc")
            End If
            previousOriginalStyle = ActiveDocument.Styles("Heading 6")

        ElseIf objPara.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("Heading 7") Then

            If objPara.Style = previousOriginalStyle Then
                objPara.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("PR5")
            Else: objPara.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("PR5lc")
            End If
            previousOriginalStyle = ActiveDocument.Styles("Heading 7")

        ElseIf objPara.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("Footer") Then
            objPara.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("EOS")

        objPara.Range.ListFormat.RemoveNumbers NumberType:=wdNumberParagraph

    End If

    'fix formatting

    With objPara.Range.Find
        With .Replacement
            .ClearFormatting
            .Font.Bold = False
            .Font.Italic = False
            .Font.Underline = False
            .Font.ColorIndex = wdBlack
            .Highlight = False
        End With
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceOne
    End With

Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Could you please provide some sample text where the code does not work, and the same text as it should look (manually corrected)? Also, please reduce the code to a representative sample - we need to test and this is too much. Make sure your tries for capitalization are included in the code. We also need the style definitions of original and new styles. All this is necessary so that we can ***test***. Just reading the problem description, there's no reason what you describe should not work. Therefore, we need to recreate the test situation. You can use the [edit] link below the question.

Comment: To set a style AllCaps you need to use 'ActiveDocument.Styles(<yourstylename>).Font.AllCaps = True

Answer (score 0):

I've revised you code to use a function to do the resetting of the style and changes the long if elseif to a select case as I suggested.  I've also simplified things by using style names rather than styles.  I think the code below accurately represents the logic in the code above, but you will now be able to see much more clearly if that logic is correct.

If there are keywords you don't understand then in the VBA IDE place the cursor on the keyword and press F1.  This will bring up the MS Help page for that keyword.

You should also install the RUbberduck addin for VBA as this has an Indenter built in plus lots of other useful and helpful tools.

You will also notice the use of .Item.  This is the default property which can be omitted but its better to leave it in.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub ChangeStyles()

    Dim objPara As Paragraph
    Dim previousOriginalStyle As String

    'junk style to use for first item
    previousOriginalStyle = ActiveDocument.Styles.Item("Quote").NameLocal

    For Each objPara In ActiveDocument.Paragraphs

        Select Case objPara.Style.NameLocal

            Case "Header"

                UpdateStyle objPara, "SCT"

            Case "Heading 1"

                UpdateStyle objPara, "PRT"
                previousOriginalStyle = "Heading 1"

            Case "Heading 2"

                UpdateStyle objPara, "ART"
                previousOriginalStyle = "Heading 2"

            Case "Heading 3"

                UpdateStyle objPara, "PR1", previousOriginalStyle, "PR1"
                previousOriginalStyle = "Heading 3"

            Case "Heading 4"

                UpdateStyle objPara, "PR2", previousOriginalStyle, "PR1lc"
                previousOriginalStyle = ActiveDocument.Styles.Item("Heading 4").NameLocal

            Case "Heading 5"

                UpdateStyle objPara, "PR3", previousOriginalStyle, "PR3lc"
                previousOriginalStyle = "Heading 5"

            Case "Heading 6"

            UpdateStyle objPara, "PR4", previousOriginalStyle, "PR4lc"
            previousOriginalStyle = "Heading 6"

            Case "Heading 7"

                UpdateStyle objPara, "PR5", previousOriginalStyle, "PR5lc"
                previousOriginalStyle = "Heading 7"

            Case "Footer"

                UpdateStyle objPara, "EOS"
                objPara.Range.ListFormat.RemoveNumbers NumberType:=wdNumberParagraph

            Case Else

            ' do nothing at the moment

        End Select

    Next

End Sub

Public Sub UpdateStyle _
( _
    ByRef ipPara As Word.Paragraph, _
    ByVal ipPrimaryStyle As String, _
    Optional ByVal ipPreviousStyle As Variant, _
    Optional ByVal ipAltStyle As Variant _
)

    If IsMissing(ipPreviousStyle) And IsMissing(ipAltStyle) Then

        ipPara.Range.ParagraphFormat.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles.Item(ipPrimaryStyle).NameLocal
        Exit Sub

    End If


    If ipPara.Range.ParagraphFormat.Style.NameLocal = ipPreviousStyle Then

        ipPara.Range.ParagraphFormat.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles.Item(ipAltStyle).NameLocal

    Else

        ipPara.Range.ParagraphFormat.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles.Item(ipPrimaryStyle).NameLocal

    End If

End Sub
```

Please be aware that whilst this code compiles OK I haven't had a chance to run it as I don't have a sample of your document.  But at least it should help get you thinking.